# Scalar variable Error in sql when using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have the `'must declare scalar variable'` error, I understand it is because my variable does not exist within the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_POLLS 
    @NAME VARCHAR (30)
AS
BEGIN
   IF @NAME = 'all'
      SELECT 
          NAME, X 
      FROM 
          data 
      WHERE 
          NAME = @NAME
END

EXEC SP_POLLS
```

But I am having a hard time understanding where I should put it inside the dynamic sql.

This stored procedure is meshing with an `ADO` call in `Excel` and this is preventing me from getting NAME and x into the Excel cells.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: For variable @NAME u got this error??

Comment: When you are getting this error

Comment: After getting the Stored procedure created if I try to use EXEC SP_POLLS I get this error

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `@NAME` as input param, you need to supply this while invoking procedure.
Like this - `EXEC SP_POLLS 'all'`

Else you will get error.

Comment: Cheers that got it all working, also thanks to mark_c as well!